How to run super linter for all the committed files not just the files in latest commit?
I'm running super linter like
name: Super Linter Java Check

on: [push]

jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Step 1: Checkout the code
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0  # Ensure full history for accurate diffing

      # Step 5: Run Super Linter
      - name: Run Super Linter
        uses: super-linter/super-linter@v7.1.0
        env:
          VALIDATE_ALL_CODEBASE: false  # Lint only the files specified
          VALIDATE_JAVA: true
          DEFAULT_BRANCH: master  # Adjust to your default branch
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

but it only checks the files in latest commit and I want to check files in all the commits in the branch.
I tried git diff to capture all the changed files but cannot pass them to super linter and I also tried FILTER_REGEX_INCLUDE to just include my committed files but that too is not working

The first easy step is to add a pull-request trigger. This will tell GitHub Actions your head branch and your base branch.
on: 
  push:
  pull_request:

and then create a pull request
